# How to count contour (inside value, outside 0) pixels on a given 2d array?

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have the following task to solve.
I have an image (numpy array) where everything that is not the main object is 0 and the main object has some pixel counts all around (let's set all of them to 1).

[image: I want to count only red squares]

What I need is to get the number of all the pixels on the contour (red squares with 1 as the value) of this object. The objects can have different forms.
Is there any way to achieve it?

OBS: The goal is to have a method that would be able to adapt to the shape of the figure, because it would be run on multiple images simultaneously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose a similar solution to @user2640045 using convolution.
We can slide a filter over the array that counts the number of neighbours (left, right, top, bottom):

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import signal
a = np.array(
    [
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
     [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0], 
     [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0], 
     [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0], 
     [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0], 
     [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0], 
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
    ]
)

filter = np.array([[0, 1, 0],
                   [1, 0, 1],
                   [0, 1, 0]])
```

Now we convolve the image array with the filter and :

```
conv = signal.convolve2d(a, filter, mode='same')
```

Every element that has more than zero and less than four neighbors while being active itself is a boundary element:

```
bounds = a * np.logical_and(conv > 0, conv < 4)
```

We can apply this mask to get the boundary pixels and sum them up:

```
>>> a[bounds].sum()
8
```

Here are 2 example inputs:

[image][image]

Comment: What happens when the value of contour pixels is greater than 1?

Comment: one would just set all values that are non-zero to one with a[a != 0] = 1

Comment: But you want to sum the values of pixels. 1 is just a placeholder in this question.

Comment: As far as I understand it, OP wants to **count** the number of boundary pixels

Comment: @PavelGomon has the point. 1 is just an example. Pixel values can vary between 0 and about 20000. But I think I got your solution. At the end, we would get a mask that we can subtract, and it will give the contour number.

Comment: yes, you would just use a[bounds].sum()

Answer (score 1):

This is interesting and I got an elegant solution for you.

Since we can agree that contour is defined as `np.array` value that is greater than `0` and have at least 1 neighbor with a value of `0` we can solve it pretty stright forward and make sure it is ready for every single image you will get for life (in an Numpy array, of course...)

```
import numpy as np 

image_pxs = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                     [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
                     [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
                     [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
                     [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
                     [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
                     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])


def get_contour(two_d_arr):
    contour_pxs = 0
    # Iterate of np:
    for i, row in enumerate(two_d_arr):
        for j, pixel in enumerate(row):
            # Check neighbors
            up = two_d_arr[i-1][j] == 0 if i > 0 else True
            down = two_d_arr[i+1][j] == 0 if i < len(image_pxs)-1 else True
            left = two_d_arr[i][j-1] == 0 if j > 0 else True
            right = two_d_arr[i][j+1] == 0 if j < len(row)-1 else True
            # Count distinct neighbors (empty / not empty)
            sub_contour = len(list(set([up, down, left, right])))
            # If at least 1 neighbor is empty and current value > 0 it is the contour
            if sub_contour > 1 and pixel > 0:
                # Add the number of pixels in i, j
                contour_pxs += pixel
    return contour_pxs
            
print(get_contour(image_pxs))
```

The output is of course 8:

```
8
[Finished in 97ms]
```